# How to align button to the right of this textarea

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a website that uses Bootstrap 4. In my design the contact form looks like this:

[image: contact form design]

But in my actual website it looks like this:

[image: contact form actual]

I've tried using floats and i've also tried creating rows and columns to get them to align correctly but nothing works.

```css
footer input, textarea {
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
} 
footer button.btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-self: flex-end;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;    
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md">
    <form action="" method="post">
      <div class="row">
        <label for="name">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="message">Asunto</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>   
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Enviar</button>        
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

All of my code: https://codepen.io/Wibblefish/pen/ZVEdqz

Thank you.

Comment: You could add some columns in your form-group row - here is an example, you just need to set the widths: https://www.bootply.com/RrFJe5REBz

Comment: I don't see "footer" in html, could you share the screen shot of your chrome with inspect on?..or just increase/decrease the height of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try making use of bootstrap's flexbox utilities :)

```css
input, textarea {
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
    border-radius: 15px;
} 

footer button.btn {
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container p-5 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" 
  <form>
    <div class=" d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column">
    <div class="form-group align-self-start">
      <label for="name" class="mx-1">Nombre</label>
      <input type="text" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group align-self-start">
      <label for="email" class="mx-3">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
      <label for="message" class="mx-2">Asunto</label>
      <textarea name="message" class="mx-2" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info align-self-end mx-2">Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Also, here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/XoJWgv) :)

Answer (score 0):

Please place your button in out side the `form-group` div

```css
 footer input, textarea {
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
} 
footer button.btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-self: flex-end;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;    
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                    <label for="name">Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email"><br>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="message">Asunto</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>   
                             
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Enviar</button>   
                    </div>  
                </form>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using custom CSS for alignment and spacing, [read the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#form-grid) and utilize Bootstrap.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-row mb-2">
        <label for="name" class="col-md-3 text-right">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="col-md-7 form-control">
     </div>
    <div class="form-row mb-2">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-3 text-right">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="col-md-7 form-control">
     </div>
    <div class="form-row mb-2">
        <label for="message" class="col-md-3 text-right">Asunto</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10"  class="col-md-7 form-control"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-md-2 align-self-end">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/nJ0HHdEB1V

With this method you want need all the extra CSS.